# How to disable applications on an Android phone with ADB interface?

Tags: android, adb

I would like to disable all USER applications on an Android phone. Disabling all these applications one by one will take some time. Is there a command I can use via the ADB shell interface to disable them?

Answer (score 0):

This command should work on all Android versions (but I do not have anything older than 5.1 to test with):

```
adb shell "for p in $(pm list packages -3); do pm disable ${p:8}; done"
```

On Android 7.0+ you could use slightly faster:

```
adb shell "for p in $(cmd package list packages -3); do pm disable ${p:8}; done"
```

And if disabling the package is not enough - you can `uninstall` it with:

```
adb shell "for p in $(cmd package list packages -3); do pm uninstall ${p:8}; done"
```

To *escape* the `$` when running the commands under Linux/macOS use `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: You can avoid the busybox requirement by running xargs on the host machine, though you may have to filter extraneous carriage returns out of the adb output to avoid confusing a unix-like xargs.