# How can I use adb to uninstall all 3rd party user apps?

Tags: android, adb, xargs

I am trying to create a script that will retrieve and uninstall all user apps in one batch operation through `adb`. Does anyone know how I would be able to do this?

I can currently list out all 3rd party apps through

```
adb shell pm list packages -3
```

Could I somehow direct the list of packages this generates into an uninstall command in `adb`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17429663/1778421

Comment: Give my man the check mark Troy :). This is clutch.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
adb shell pm list packages -3 | cut -d':' -f2 | tr '\r' ' ' | xargs -r -n1 -t adb uninstall
```

- First part is to get 3rd party app package names
- second part is to split package names using delimiter `:`
- third part is to replace carriage return with space (sometimes it would be a problem in linux machines. Try removing this part and check if you face it)
- and the last one is for uninstalling one by one

  - `r` option will prevent xargs from running the command if there are no third party apps installed
  - `n1` option is to pass one result value as argument at a time to the command
  - `t` is for printing the command being executed)

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I have executed the above command. It is telling 'cut' in not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Please tell me where i am failing. My adb is up and running and it it is listing the device serial id.

Comment: cut is a linux command. It seems that you are running on Windows.

Comment: Write the output of adb command to a file and use a 'for loop' to cut and uninstall. ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4442121/3604656

Comment: But, in my another Windows machine same command is working. Is there any difference here?? Both windows machines are of same configuration.

Comment: Are you using command prompts that supports GNU tools..? Like Cygwin or git bash in the other windows system..

Comment: Mac OS X Terminal gives me: "xargs: illegal option -- r". I tried removing the 3rd section, which changed the error to: "xargs: replacements must be a number". I believe my ADB is set up correctly.

Comment: Please replace "xargs -r" with "xargs -I" in Mac . Ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/285170

Answer (score 2):

What seems to be the problem? It can be done with this one-liner:

```
adb shell "pm list packages -3 | cut -c9- | xargs pm uninstall"
```

Comment: The phones I'm testing are not rooted, is there any way to do this without root?

Answer (score 0):

MacOS 13.5.2

**adb devices**
List of devices attached

```
068162518J104381    device
adb-068162518J104381-uQtyOp._adb-tls-connect._tcp.  device
```

**adb -s 068162518J104381 shell**

TECNO-CG7n: **pm list packages -3**

```
package:org.iggymedia.periodtracker
package:com.alibaba.aliexpresshd
```

TECNO-CG7n: **pm list packages -3 | cut -c9- | xargs -r -n1 -t pm uninstall**

```
pm uninstall org.iggymedia.periodtracker 
Success

pm uninstall com.alibaba.aliexpresshd 
Success
```